# Reload Javascript file (including event, variable etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript file that creates a chatbox UI with alot of event listeners and variables.

Is it possible to completely remove/unload an executed javascript file and execute it again? I have tried to remove the script or the DOM elements and include it again but the variables and event listeners from the previous code still exist.

Comment: Put your javascript code in function and call it whenever you want.

Comment: the question is, why do you need to remove the event listeners only to re-add the same listeners again. I think your problem is different to what you imagine it to be

Comment: because if i include the listener the 2nd time without removing the previous listener, the event will trigger twice. tested @JaromandaX

Comment: yes, I understand the problems you are having by loading the script a second time. My point was that it's odd to even need to load the script a second time, only to re-attach listeners you want to remove in the first place ... net result would be that the same listeners on the same elements - why do you need to refresh the listeners at all if they're already attached

Comment: a little insight into your code may allow someone to show an alternative that doesn't require such unusual processes

Comment: good question, but it is so hard to explain here even with my code. the code is so huge and the variables(some flag etc) and UI/event listener changes throughout the process.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/imsy041/rd4q469y/  -- this is the code, of course i could've given this in the first place but my code is really messy and unorganized and poor

Comment: this is a client side embed js file. the variables and UI changes throughout the process as i mentioned, i use sockjs to do the messaging and retrieve the settings (in an object) from my server side. since the object and all those listeners are already executed, unless i clean up all the variable(settings/flag) and listener then remove the DOM elements it will never be same as a f5 fresh start? so is it not possible to reload a js file? by reload i mean removing all the executed js code and run it again

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible unless your code is designed to be re-used and can cleanup after itself.

For instance if you design your script as:

```
function initSomePlugin(targetEl) {
    targetEl.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

    return destroy;

    function handleClick() {
        console.log('clicked!');
    }

    function destroy() {
        targetEl.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }
}
```

The you can do:

```
 let destroyPlugin = initSomePlugin(someElement);
 destroyPlugin();
 initSomePlugin(someOtherElement);
```

Comment: ya, so this is the only way? like i said i have alot of listeners and variables to clean up

Comment: @LimSY That is the only way. It may be implemented differently, but in the end your code must do it explicitly. There is no way of undoing the operations of an arbitrary script that ran. If your code is poorly designed I agree that this would be tedious, but it really shouldn't be that hard.